# Fill Object List<Object> with complex XML file,

Tags: c#, xml, list

I'm a beginner C# developer, actually, i'm coding a game.
My question is about load an XML from my windows phone app.

I have a list of object that I'd like to fill with my xml's element.
But the problem is that I can't serialize more than one Element.
I'd like to store data (image's position) in my list.

Maybe my code will help you better understand what I mean

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Map
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int IdTexture { get; set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Buildings")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Building")]
    public List<Buildings> Build_list { get; set; } 
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Trees")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Tree")] 
    public List<Trees> Trees_list { get; set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Rocks")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Rock")]
    public List<Rock> Rock_list { get; set; }
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Roads")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Road")]
    public List<Road> Road_list { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement]
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Bornes")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Borne")]
    public List<Bornes> Bornes_list { get; set; }


    public void Map()
    {
        Build_list = new List<Buildings>();
        Trees_list = new List<Trees>();
        Rock_list = new List<Rock>();
        Road_list = new List<Road>();
        Bornes_list = new List<Bornes>();
     }
```

what should I use?

Comment: The xsd.exe utility can generate the kind of code you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Thats what  i have finally done (even if the generated code is not the easiest). Do you have an exemple of how Deserialize it then and how read values ?